# How to find $\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{t^2-2|t|+1}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> How to find $\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{t^2-2|t|+1}dt$
>   where x>0.

I tried to know how will the Wolfram  treat with absolute term and how to find this integral, but I found that the Wolfram couldn't catch this integral. Can anyone help me to find this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where the $x>1$
$$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{t^2-2|t|+1}dt=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{(\sqrt{t^2}-1)^2}dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{x}||t|-1|dt=\int_{0}^{1}||t|-1|dt+\int_{1}^{x}||t|-1|dt$$
for $x\le 1$
$$=\int_{0}^{x}||t|-1|dt$$

Answer (score 2):

If $x > 0$, then the interval of integration is $t \in [0,x]$, and on this interval $|t| = t$.  Therefore, the integrand is simply $$\sqrt{t^2 - 2|t| + 1} = \sqrt{t^2 - 2t + 1} = |t-1|.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Perhaps you could simplify the integrand having this in mind:

$$t^2=|t|^2$$